# Rigify Messes Up Model

Tags: mesh, rigify

So, I'm working on making a rig for my creature, Pliecce. When I generate my rigify rig and parent it with automatic weights, this happens to the head:

[image]
how mesh looks after parenting.

I don't know why this is happening, but it is. I tried many things: separating parts, checking normals, looking at youtube videos, moving parts of the rig, moving the model's jaw, and some more, which I won't list. I looked at other post, which didn't give me the solution. Someone please help, I've been having this problem for weeks now.

It's only the head that's not working correctly, and the stretched out pink is it's tongue. Here's the file

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE. You can upload files by opening https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions.

Comment: Thank you, I uploaded the file.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to apply your rig again, try clearing parent with alt+P< clear and keep all transformations and then parenting your bones.

To explain what's going on, when a new parent replaces the old parent, the child object looses any transformation from the old parent, creating unexpected effects.

Comment: no luck at all sadly, I'm using automatic weights.

Comment: I suggest trying the same when using automatic weights. That's what I assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Nice character.

The problem seems to be the Rigify head. It is probably a bug. Notice that when you generate your rig, it measures thousands of meters in Y and Z. This is probably due to the way the head bones are stretched to fit the shape of the creature.

I am not sure what I could do. I would submit a bug report. But don't hold your breath. Rigify doesn't get as much love as other modules and the head is going to be deprecated sooner or later. So the devs can't be bothered to fix problems with it.

Comment: removing bones seem to help stop the mesh from going all over the place

Comment: it's looking a lot better, but the face is still bad.